# Cutting a column and then inserting with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Columns("DV").Cut
Columns("P").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

I am using this code above to basically move a column, but every time I run the macro, it slows the process so much. Is there a more efficient way to do this so my macro isn't bogged down?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me also make an update to say that the macro first creates a copy then within the copy my copy performs the above code.

Comment: What is your full code?

Answer (score 1):

You might try inserting this line at the beginning of the macro:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

And insert this at the end:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

If you have a lot of formulas in the data you are moving around it is attempting to recalculate while the macro is running.  The above lines will tell Excel to not calculate during the macro run.

Comment: That didn't effect the macro.  The Macro first pastes values then creates a copy then moves the column on the copy so there are no formulas that have to recalculate.

Comment: How many rows and columns are you dealing with?  I assume a lot since you're going up to DW.  The answer may be to copy in steps instead of making one big copy and then moving the data around.  I.E _Columns("A:O").copy Sheets(yourSheet).Columns("A:O")_, then _Columns("DV").copy Sheets(yourSheet).Columns("P")_, then _Columns("P:DV").copy Sheets(yourSheet).Columns("Q:DW")_, etc.  *edit* This solution requires making a new blank sheet to copy the data into first.